# Can't send image through http request when using api route middleware

Tags: reactjs, express, http, next.js, multer

I'm trying to send an image to my backend from my next.js frontend, but when i do that, the file uploads as a corrupt file. However if i make my request through postman, the image uploads correctly.

This is the button that displays the input to upload the image from computer

```
<Button label="Attach JPG" onClick={() => inputRef.current?.click()}>
    <input id="file" type="file" hidden={true} ref={inputRef} accept=".jpg" onChange={handleImageUpload} />
</Button>
```

This is my handleImageUpload function

```
const handleImageUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (!file) return;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    fetch('/api/b/api/upload-attachment', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {//... my keys},
        body: formData
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => setImageURL(res.fileURL))
};
```

This is the api route where the request gets redirected (located in pages/api/b/[[...slug]].ts)

```
export default async function forwarder(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const baseUrl = process.env.API_URL;
    const url = req.url!.replace('/api/b', '');
    try {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: req.method,
            url: `${baseUrl}${url}`,
            headers: req.headers,
            data: req.body,
            responseType: 'stream',
        });
        data.pipe(res);
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.error(e.message);
        res.status(500).json({ trace: e.message });
    }
}
```

And this is the backend route

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => createFileName(req, file) // dont worry about this
});

const upload = multer({ 
  storage,
  limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,},
});

router.post('/upload-attachment', upload.single('file'), (req: AuthedRequest, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK', message: 'File uploaded successfully', fileURL: req.file?.path })
})
```

Things that i tried:

- Adding content-type: 'multipart/form-data' to the request
- Copying the request as postman specifies in the code section